# Find all occurrences of each element of an array in another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array here:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7]
```

and another,

```
b = [1, 2, 5]
```

I want to find all occurrences of each element of array `b` in `a`. i.e. I want a resultant array like this:

```
result = [1, 1, 2, 5, 5]
```

I was going through the [Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4) to find any combination of methods which would give me the result, but haven't managed to do so. Does anyone know how I can get the `result` array? I prefer to use a very concise solution (i.e. without too many loops etc), and usually Lodash is best for that, but other solutions are also fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd just filter the first array based on the second array

```js
var a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7];
var b = [1, 2, 5];

var result = a.filter( z => b.indexOf(z) !== -1 );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for..of` loops to iterate `b` check if element of `a` is equal to current element in `b`

```js
let a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7];

let b = [1, 2, 5];

let result = [];

for (let prop of b) {
  for (let el of a) {
    if (el === prop) result = [...result, el]
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I really want to make it concise.:)

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to use _, you could use 2 _.difference calls.

```js
var a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7];
var b = [1, 2, 5];

var result = _.difference(a,_.difference(a,b));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```